# I did in all view return no of landscpe orientation but i have to show only one view of spreadsheet in landscape mode how to do it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

suppose i have multiple view in app but i have to show only one view  of spreadsheet in        landscape mode how to please any suggest to me .and one thing is that i did in all view return no of landscape view please any one give me idea about that it would be a pleasure for me

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
 }
```

Comment: Keep condition like this in shouldautorotate in the desired view `interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in iOS 6

The these two methods can help you in this case.

1 - Supported Interface Orientations

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

2 - Preferred Interface Orientation For Presentation

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: i  have shown all view in portrait view because i do not have to show that view in landscape view .so i have to do it only one view and i am not working ios6 please give me solution about it ...

Comment: I post another answer try that

Comment: In  my view i have tab bar also and i will have to adjust it also so please let me know about it because view is rotating in landscape but tab bar and navigation bar is not rotating.

Comment: Replace [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform] with  [self.navigationController setTransform:landscapeTransform];

Comment: Both the method is not calling in my code please give me better idea about that..

Answer (score 0):

try this in your viewWillAppear of that View

```
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +100.0);

[self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
```